# Flask: How to transfer an element from one app.route to another

Tags: python, html, flask, button

I am currently working on a project in which I have an archive, in which you should be able to remove videos from a button in a webpage. As I implement the webpage via python I have troubles naming the name of the button as the index, (idx) declared in the for loop. I need to have the name of the button clicked (index) (or directly the file name) in the /delete app route but cannot figure out how to transfer it properly. The Button itself works.

```
@app.route('/archive' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def archive():  
  
    path = "/home/pi/Videos/"
    print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :")  
    dir_list = os.listdir(path) 
    dir_list.sort()               # The List
    

    output = '''<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">... #just some styling
        <div class = Box>
        <div class = flex-box>'''
    
    
    for idx, file in enumerate(dir_list):              #For loop through each element
            
            output += "<div style = 'background: black;'>"+ file +  "</div>" + ''' <form method='post' action='myip/delete'>
    <input class='btn' type='submit' name=idx value='Delete'> </form> ''' 
    output += "</div></div>"
    return output

    
@app.route('/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_file():
      output = request.form['idx'] 
      os.remove(THEFILEIWANTTODELETE)                    #HERE I NEED TO HAVE THE INDEX OR FILE NAME/ROUTE
      return redirect(url_for('archive'))
```

I already tried getting the index, but only got the value of the button.

Comment: Why are you building the HTML in python through string concatenation? There's a reason that `jinja2` is included in the pallets project for rendering variables in the template

Comment: `name=idx value='Delete'` conveys nothing to the backend about the _specific_ entry you want to remove. In fact, I _think_ you think `name=idx` actually alters on each loop - it doesn't. That's a literal value and I'm not sure how HTML handles non-strings here

Comment: Never heard of jinja2, but I couldnt get it working otherwise as php does not get executed via render_template.

Comment: Yes i know that it does not convey anything to the backend, that was just for troubleshooting, my question was how to make it convey something in the backend

Comment: Do you might have another approach that I could try? I cannot get it working in any way.

Comment: `jinja2` is effectively built in to `flask` with `render_template`. I don't want to sound awful, but there is a _lot_ wrong with this setup. I really recommend you look into the Flask Mega Tutorial to get the basics worked out, otherwise you're going to run head-on into problem after problem

Comment: Basically, you need a `templates` directory, put a `.html` in that for your page, and build a `for` loop with some list passed from the backend so you'd have something lat looks like `name = {{ idx }}` in your HTML. It's way too much to try fix in a single answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, here's a possible solution to start with.

To display the page, as @roganjosh mentioned, you can use jinja with either [`render_template`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.render_template) or [`render_template_string`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.render_template_string). [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) is a built-in template engine that you can pass a template and a dictionary with data to. This data can then be used in various ways within the template based on its key

To specify the file to delete, I think the easiest way is to send the filename. In this case a path within a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) is used.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template_string, 
    url_for
)
import os 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/archive')
def archive():  
    path = '/home/pi/Videos/'

    dir_list = os.listdir(path) 
    dir_list.sort()
    
    return render_template_string(
        '''
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <!-- ... -->
        <body>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="flex-box">
                    {% for file in dir_list -%}
                    <div>
                        {{ file }}
                        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('.delete', filename=file) }}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        ''', 
        **locals()
    )

@app.post('/delete/<path:filename>')
def delete(filename):
    path = '/home/pi/Videos/'
    try: 
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
    except: pass
    return redirect(url_for('archive'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have gone for anotherr approach just by changing my "idx" in output to "file" and it worked. Thanks!